# Retrive records in buckets from a freq. updating transactional table based on limit and offset from SQL Server into data warehouse resulting duplicate

Tags: sql-server, database, duplicates, limit, offset

I have a pipeline that will load data from SQL Server to a warehouse based on the limit and offset by partitioning it into five buckets.

Since the data from the source is updating frequently, for every retrieval data reordering happens for new limit and offset query fetch, resulting in data duplicates on my warehouse. (My guess with the issue)

How do I overcome this?

Thanks.

Comment: The link you have posted is for MySQL, but you have tagged SQL Server? SQL Server doesn't have limit and offset, so what actually are you doing?

Comment: Hi, @DaleK Didn't get the exact solution but I'm trying on this path.., Let me know if you have any inputs >

Comment: Please clarify whether you are using SQL Server or MySQL, because if SQL Server you aren't using Limit & Offset - in which case please show what you are using.

Comment: select * from TABLE_NAME order by COLUMNS OFFSET 50000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50000 ROWS ONLY

This is the query I'm using in sql server

Comment: [edit] any clarifications into your question - and remove the references to limit and offset, they just confuse the situation since they are MySQL.

Comment: Okay thanks for suggestion, did that @DaleK